# How to set Default home app programmatically

Tags: android, android-launcher

I want to make my android app to set a home app(default launcher app when click on home button). I already set the `intent-filter` in **manifest file**

```
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

but after starting the application if i click on back button a window appear on screen and ask to confirm this activity as a home. Can it possible to set programmatically OR via adb command ?

In logcat i have seen the action when i complete by selecting my app as home is like this:

```
07-30 16:56:16.809 1289-2215/? I/PackageManager: Replacing preferred activity com.myapp.hp/.MainActivity for user 0:
07-30 16:56:16.809 1289-2215/? I/PackageManager:   Action: "android.intent.action.MAIN"
07-30 16:56:16.809 1289-2215/? I/PackageManager:   Category: "android.intent.category.HOME"
07-30 16:56:16.809 1289-2215/? I/PackageManager:   Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-30 16:56:16.809 1289-2215/? I/PackageManager:   AutoVerify=false
```

Comment: this is something currently possbile through manifest only

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1:**  You need to have root access of your devices to unistall the default launcher

**Step 2:**  To uninstall  default launcher   `adb uninstall app.package`

Then go to  home screen app you want . then go to settings and set it as default

**Note:** it is possible only rooted devices

> **If you want to do using adb command**
>
> First you need to delete default launcher Then you need to move your launchera.apk inside system app.... go inside
>   system->media->default->you need place your apk here...
>   May be path will differ each and every firmware

Comment: Well i already have root access. I know this how to do this manually or launch Home Setting Activity which show me to select my application as a home application. What i have write in my question that I WANT TO DO THIS EITHER PROGRAMMATICALLY OR VIA ADB COMMAND.

Comment: I love searching for a question and getting to read somebody yelling and screaming just because he didn't get the right answer...

Comment: @GlennMaynard can you try this 'adb shell cmd package set-home-activity "package/activity"'

adb reboot